# Cannot perform a Redirect within Slim Framework controller __construct()

Tags: php, slim

I have an application in Slim Framework v3. There are 2 controllers, `classes/FrontController.php` and `classes/AdminController.php`.

`AdminController.php` is for Admin functionality (un-surprisingly!) and the `FrontController.php` for "public" part of the application.

Various routes have been defined in `/index.php` which run functions in these controllers - all normal.

What I'm trying to do is write a single piece of code (without repeating it all over) inside `AdminController::__construct()` such that it will redirect users to `FrontController::index()` if they try and access any Admin routes via URL manipulation.

The code which I have in my AdminController is like this:

```
public function __construct(Slim\Container $ci) {
    $this->ci = $ci;
    if (!$this->_isAdmin()) {
        return $this->ci->response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/index');
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything even though `$this->_isAdmin()` returns false - I've even tested it by *only* returning false irrespective of the result the database would return under normal operation. My expectation is that it would redirect at this point, but it instead goes and loads up `AdminController::index()` if I try and access `/admin` in the browser.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the fact that the response cannot be manipulated in the constructor? How can I handle this?

For information the routes in my `index.php` are like this:

```
$app->get('/', '\FrontController:index')->setName('/index');
$app->get('/admin', '\AdminController:index');
// many other routes...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return an Response object inside an constructor. A constructor is for constructing the object, so the return value does nothing, you should either use middleware for this or make this check in every route method.

```
$app->get('/admin', '\AdminController:index')->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    if(user is not admin) {
        return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/index');
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: Using the above approach though, you would presumably have to add a similar thing to *every* route? So there's no advantage in that over just adding the logic inside each route method? It's certainly not very DRY!

Comment: @Andy You could use the grouped routes see [Router of Slim3](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html) search for `Route groups` there you could add the middleware to the group then you wouldn't need to add this to every route. You could also add a global middleware and then check for starting url `/admin`. Or you could add an own [error handler](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html) and throw an access denied exception and catch it there.